# Category and tags goes 404

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy

I made a custom theme for a website and I'm having some trouble with the category and tag pages, since they redirect to pages with the same slug or to 404 (when there is no pages).

On my website I have 3 custom type posts, each with about two customs taxonomies (none of then with category or tag as name).

Besides that I also using the custom permalink %postname% and all the site beside that two pages are working fine.

My .htaccess look like this:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /brazcubas/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /brazcubas/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I don't know what I'm maybe doing wrong.

What I've already tried was:

- Disable and Enable the permalink structure.
- Create custom category pages
- Create custom archives pages
- Change to other theme.

Even with other themes the error still going.

What could it be?

Comment: I looked in the database and noted that the category and tags isn't on the field rewrite_rules from the options table.

Comment: Sorry I didn't wait for an answer, but I found and solved the error.


While making the custom taxonomies and post types I used the method flush_rewrite_rules(false) and this was killing the category and tag rewrite_rule and keeping all the customs. 


So removing those lines solved the problem.